# How to finish this loop?

Tags: pages, templates, taxonomy, child-pages

I had already asked a question of how to get only get the child pages of a parent page that belonged to a certain taxonomy. A very helpful user gave me the answer to this, however, I was not provided the code to go either side of the loop so that I could get: the title, featured image and excerpt. The code I was given is this:

```
$child_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
"SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = $post->ID AND post_type = 'page' ORDER      BY menu_order"
);

 $args = array(
'post__in' => $child_ids, // Only retrieve taxonomy posts that are children of this page
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'top5',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $post->post_title
    ),
),
);
```

So if anyone could tell me how to use this to pull the title, excerpt and featured image that would be great thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the very helpful user gave you a wrong answer. Here a example which I think is better:

```
 //The ID of the parent page, for example 4. Change to the correct ID.
 //For example, if you are in the page loop, you can use get_the_ID() to get ID of current page
 $parent_id = 4;

 //The terms that the page belongs to.
 $terms = array( 'one_term', 'another_term' );

 $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'page',
      'post_parent' => $parent_id,
      'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'top5',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    =>  $terms
           )
       )
 );

 $query = new WP_Query( $args );

 if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

     //Start the loop
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

         $query->the_post();

         //Do whatever you want with the found pages. For example:
         the_title();
         if( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
             the_post_thumbnail();
     }
         the_content();

     }
     //End the loop

     wp_reset_postdata();

  } else {

    //Do something if pages have not been found

  }
```

NOTE: By default, "pages" doesn't have taxonomies, so I assume that you have registered the "top5" taxonomy for "pages" post type. Also, you say that you want to get the excerpt of the pages and by default pages has no support for excerpt, so I assume you have added excerpts support for pages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer!, yes I have registered taxonomies and excerpts, problem is this template has to work on a lot of different pages and so using individual parent id's is not necessarily all that practical, is there a way to make the post parent $id the current page?

Comment: You have to elaborate your question and be more specific. For example, if you want that the parent id to be dynamic, we need to now where the code is executed. I didn't now that information so I can't know what parent id you want, thats why I hardcoded a parent id as example.

Comment: Sorry about that, I basically want this code in the page template file of the parent page, which will be used across around 15 pages. I want to use it to call the children pages of the parent page, however, only those that belong to a certain taxonomy. For example I can have lots of child pages, but it will only bring in those that belong to the 'top5' taxonomy. So the parent page id would have to be dynamic to the id of the current parent page, if that makes sense? Sorry if I haven't made it clear, its difficult to put in words.

Comment: See edited code.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I will try that right away. Only on ething would I not have to use `<?php echo $pageChild->post_title ?>` for example, to get the title of the child page or has the loop already done this part for me. Sorry, I am a little novice with wordpress as have you only just started using it, so I thank you for your patience!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I have figured it all out now, the only problem with the code above is that you left out the last closing bracket `)` of the `'tax_query'   => array(`. Otherwise this is amazing thank you so very much!

Comment: Sorry the missing `)`. Fixed.